# WordPress Newsletter plugin redirect to previous page after subscription confirmation

Tags: wordpress

I am stuck with a problem I WordPress. I have integrated Newsletter plugin in the footer of my site. After subscription the page redirects to another page which does not exist. What I need is it should redirect to same page from where the user has subscribed. I tried many options but i didn't find any solution.

This is the plugin that I have integrated in my application.
https://wordpress.org/plugins/newsletter/

Waiting for a response....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this PHP shortcode of the plugin in which you can pass the current URL to the `confirmation_url` shortcode attribute.

```
<?php
global $wp;
echo do_shortcode('[newsletter_form confirmation_url="'.home_url( $wp->request ).'"]');
?>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Go to Newsletter - Setting and more
Select Dedicated Page, by default it must be "Newsletter" Page. If there is something else then select Newsletter Page and you're done.

Comment: If i want to redirect it to the same page from where it has subscribed, then?

Comment: check documentation https://www.thenewsletterplugin.com/documentation/subscription#welcome

Comment: Go to Newsletter Dashboard, there will be Menu on top Navigate to List Building the Subscription, there You will get